# Symfony2 safe data from second entity's form in table of first entity

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony

how can I save the data from my created form , which is using 2 entitys to output different select and input fields, into the table of the first entity.

Main Entity is Tasks.php - in this form I get also data from 2 other Entities called TaskTypes and User.

It looks like this:

```
$AddTask = new Tasks();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($AddTask)
    ->add('task_title', 'text', array('label' => 'Aufgabentitel', 'attr' => array('class' => 'first')))
    ->add('task_description', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Aufgabenbeschreibung'))
    ->add('task_types', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'SeotoolMainBundle:TaskTypes',
        'property' => 'task_type_title',
        'label' => 'Aufgabentyp'))

    ->add('user', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'SeotoolMainBundle:User',
        'property' => 'username',
        'label' => 'Kundenzuordnung',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ( $request ) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
                    ->orderBy('w.username', 'ASC')
                    ->where('w.isAdmin = 0')
                    ->andWhere('w.isActive = 1');
        }
    ))
    ->add('Aufgabe anlegen', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {


    $task = new Tasks();
    $task->setTaskTitle($request->request->get('form')['task_title']);
    $task->setTaskDescription($request->request->get('form')['task_description']);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($task);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('add_task'));

}
```

My Entity/Tasks.php looks like this:

```
...
/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskTypes")
 */
protected $tasktypes;

/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User")
 */
protected $user;
...
    public function getTaskTypes()
{
    return $this->tasktypes;
}

public function setTaskTypes(TaskTypes $tasktypes = null)
{
    $this->tasktypes = $tasktypes;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(User $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

I got these code snippets out of an example how to make forms with multiple entities. But I don't get it working to save the data from the "extern entity" in the table of the "main entity"

What I tried:

```
...
   /**
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskTypes")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $tasktypes;

/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $user;

....

public function getTaskTypes()
{
    return $this->tasktypes;
}

public function setTaskTypes()
{
   return $this->tasktypes;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(User $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

It outputs following error:

> Neither the property "task_types" nor one of the methods "addTaskTyp()"/"removeTaskTyp()", "addTaskType()"/"removeTaskType()", "setTaskTypes()", "taskTypes()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Tasks".
>   500 Internal Server Error - NoSuchPropertyException

Comment: What happens if you change `task_types` to `tasktypes` in your `createFormBuilder` method?

Comment: Neither the property "TaskTypes" nor one of the methods "addTaskTyp()"/"removeTaskTyp()", "addTaskType()"/"removeTaskType()", "setTaskTypes()", "taskTypes()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Tasks".
500 Internal Server Error - NoSuchPropertyException

Comment: You need to get some consistency in your code. You have a method `setTaskTypes()`, which assumes it will be setting a variable named `taskType`, but in your case is actually called `tasktype`. Hence the message `Neither the property "TaskTypes" nor one of the methods...` you are getting. I first recommend changing the property name to `$taskType` throughout your `Task` class

Comment: I renamed the properity name to the same name convention i used for the other ones... "task_type"

But it all won't work.... again getting this exception:
Neither the property "task_type" nor one of the methods "addTaskType()"/"removeTaskType()", "setTaskType()", "taskType()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Tasks". //// protected $task_type; //// public function getTaskType()
    {
        return $this->task_type;
    }

Comment: Did you name it `taskType`? Not `task_type`. The variable `task_type` is not matching with the method `setTaskType()`

Comment: It looks like he don't find anything....maybe the mistake is at another point of my code? - because he searched for setTaskType() but can't find it in my Tasks.php Entity - but it is in there.

Comment: Yes, also when i name it taskType it will give this exception:
Neither the property "taskType" nor one of the methods "addTaskType()"/"removeTaskType()", "setTaskType()", "taskType()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Tasks".

Comment: Alex, now i get another error. What I did was to delete all and generating new getter and setters. Now my Proifiler says:  
[task_title => rrgef, task_description => ewsdgv, taskTypes => 17, Aufgabe anlegen => , _token => Y9PyTjcYjl1lGrXNvsPKcp_yqXbgEDZNIlHERuFshq8] /// And Exception is: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tasks (task_title, task_description, task_type, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["rrgef", "ewsdgv", null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'task_type' cannot be null

Comment: This is because you are not entering a value into the `task_type` field in the database, which demands that you do. You can either, 1) make sure you pass a value to it, or 2) make the field allow a null value. To do that, in your entity class, for that property, change `@ORM\Column(type="integer")` to `@ORM\Column(type="integer" nullable=true)` and update the database on the command line

Comment: Ok, now he makes an entry without any exception. But there's one thing I don't understand. He makes taskType and user NULL. But Why? My Profiler tells me, there are values in the Post Request. Why won't they put into the database?

Comment: Ohhh Alex - thank you :D I got it! Of course I also have to tell my controller to add the value....I thought it will be done automaticly. Thank you so much!!! :-D You can add an answer, I will mark is as solved.

Comment: Have added an answer. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discrepancy between your property names, and the getter and setter methods. Regenerate your getters and setters to ensure that they are matched correctly.

As it stands, you will not be able to add a null value into the `task_type` field in the database. To change this, you can declare it in your annotation:

```
@ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
```

And then update the database schema.

Comment: Thank you! Works :-)
Just need a decimal point ( comma ) after integer" ,

Comment: Great, have fixed the type.